# ShowDialog issue while opening form

Tags: c#, .net, windows, c#-4.0

I have 2 forms

Form1

Form2

I have one button in Form1

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            Form2 f2 =new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog();
            f2.Dispose();
         }
```

but issue is while opening form it's bliking and diasparing

i have tried to use show() also but not solved the problem

If i have not used Disposed method then first time when run the form it appering and disappered but sencond time onward by clicking on button it's working fine...

In Form2_Load event i am using this two property

```
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               this.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
               this.RightToLeftLayout = true;            
            }
```

Comment: I doubt the code you posted might not cause any issue, `ShowDialog()` will block everything after that.

Comment: In Form2_Load method i am using this two property           this.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
this.RightToLeftLayout = true;

Comment: Yes the code you posted above seems to be okay.. if possible add form2 code as well..

Comment: May i know why you are using this property? this.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;

Comment: I want Form2 in Arabic Style (Right to left)

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the form layout while its loading. Change it before you launch. Remove the code from `Form2_Load` and put it in `button1_Click`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 =new Form2();
    f2.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
    f2.RightToLeftLayout = true;
    f2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: And please use `using` to have the form disposed automatically after `ShowDialog`. Also, if you want a dialog that's modal, please use `ShowDialog(this)` to indicate to the dialog who's the parent window.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you want to **show** and **close** the `form2` using the same button. And I doubt your initial problem description

> "issue is while opening form it's bliking and diasparing"

I think `form2` is not 'blinking' while opening, but is 'blinking' while you try to click the button again in `form1`

`ShowDialog()` will exit your execution after u called it. Mean, it will exit the execution after you click the button.

Thus, you should try `Show()` with conditional statement within the button click event

In form1.cs

```
    bool flag = false;
    Form2 frm2;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag == false)
        {
            frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.Show();
            frm2.Load += new EventHandler(frm2_Load);
            frm2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(frm2_FormClosed);
            flag = true;
        }
        else
        {
            frm2.Close();
            flag = false;
        }

    }

    void frm2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set what ever properties you like
    }

    void frm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        flag = false;
    }
```

See also: [A dialog disables all of the windows that your program displays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742819/3-forms-show-and-showdialog-not-working-as-expected-bug?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this Property

```
this.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
```

and  run your form...

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            using(Form2 f2 =new Form2())
            {
              f2.ShowDialog();
            }

         }
```